# ¿Como pasar los datos de un datagridview cargado a otro formulario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, datagridview

Tengo un datagridview cargado desde la Base de Datos y quiero pasara los datos de ese datagridview a otro formulario pero al momento de pasarlos solo me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el datagrid cargado 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta manera es que llamo al form2 en el boton buscar

```
 Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        codigofactura.Text = frm.getNumberFactura();
```

de esta forma es que mando los datos del datagrid al formulario principal

```html
 private void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conexion.Open();
            codFactura = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].ToString();
            getNumberFactura();
        }

        public string getNumberFactura()
        {
            this.Close();
            return codFactura;
        }
```

Comment: no puedo ver tu imagen, el datagrid esta en el form Padre y quiere enviar datos el Form hijo? o abres del form hijo quieres regresarlos al form padre?

Comment: si,quiero mandarlo de uno al otro

Comment: no entiendo form1 tiene el datagrid y de ahi quieres pasarlos al form2 o como??

Comment: quiero pasarlos del form2  al form 1 , en el form2 esta el datagrid cargado desde la BD

Comment: voy tratando de entender, lanzas el sistema y te abre el form1 de este form1 abres el form2 aqui esta el dagrid cargado dB, entonces quieres regresar datos al form1? es correcto

Comment: si, exactamente

Comment: ok, quieres pasar toda la fila que seleccionas? todo el datagrid? o solo la celda que seleccionas?

Comment: quiero pasar los datos que tengan el mismo codigo, si no que ahi solo guarde una sola factura

Comment: Donde esta el metodo que carga tu grilla? Esta desordenado tu codigo, no entiendo que pertenece a que clase y porque hacer un metodo para devolver una variable que esta asignada en otro metodo

Comment: primero es ordenarlos, si son el mismo codigo, entonces hacer un array con esos codigos iguales ir recorriendo y sacando los datos para regresarlos al form1, imagino que hay un datagrid donde quieres mostrar los datos del codigo que se repiten?

Comment: @Manny y ahi no esta organizado? si, si ahi un datagrid donde quiero mostrar los datos

Comment: @Fernandez puse mi respuesta con lo que entendi preguntando, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar el valor de la celda, siempre utilizo el evento `CellContentClick` de la grilla.

```
private void grilla_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   var id = grilla.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

un ejemploe sencillo no estoy seguro de que funcione copiando y pegando, quizas tengas que adaptarlo pero deberia de funcionar.
Este codigo deberia de ir en el evento CellDoubleClick de tu datagrid donde estan los datos cargados.

```
string Cod;
if(e.ColumnIndex == 0)//0 es la columna de tu Codigo cambialo a tu necesidad
        {

            Cod = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            string[] repetidos = dataGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => Convert.ToString(x.Cells[0].Value)).ToArray();// este es el array que contendra los codigos repetidos.
            for (int i = 0; i < repetidos.Length;)
            {
                //foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGrid.Rows )
                //{
                    if (Cod == repetidos[i])
                    {
                        //Aqui puedes crear un datatable y retornarlo a tu form1 y asignarlo a tu datagrid y listo!
                        //http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2009/09/c-comunicar-formularios-de-forma.html
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    i++;
                //}

            }
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda mi respuesta :)

Comment: ahi alguna manera de hacerlo con el codigo que tengo??

Comment: la verdad es que no entiendo tu codigo, quizas falten comenetarios en las lineas de codigo para poder entender.

Comment: mi respuesta esta basada en los preguntas que te hice en los comentarios.

Comment: ese es todo mi codigo solo que no coloque la variable que defino que es codFactura

Comment: la otra cosa es que tengo que hacerlo de esa manera para ahorrar mas lineas de codigo

Comment: es complicado hacerlo con unas simples lineas de codigo, yo utilizo linq que es una manera "facil" y de "ahorrar" lineas, pero si hay alguna otra manera yo tambien quiero saberlo.

Comment: con eso se supone que deberia traer todos los datos que esten el codigo

Comment: se crea un array con los codigos iguales llamado "repetidos" luego recorremos ese arrary con un for, dentro del if los vamos comparando el codigo con el que llenaste el array contra los datos deltro del array si son iguales, entonces los agregas a un datatable y ese sera el return para tu form1. el foreach no es necesario ponerlo